# Drive Api V3 - How to name file being uploaded?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Working with the google drive api through rest, and making sure I understand what fields and content should be provided as headers and on the body. Just a few one off's that don't quite match up. I'm using postman to make my requests currently before I run off and write the code I need to.

Just to be clear, Authorization is setup, and is working fine. (I have another request that shares a file just fine.)

So, I understand that I'm supposed to create a Post Request to 
`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files`

My parameters include the `uploadType` which is set to Media, because it's less than 5MB. The remainder of the parameters are optional or default to false, which is what I want. It's the request body that's the problem.

I have my request body like this:

[image: Postman Request Body]

The issue is that I get a response object that states the file was successfully uploaded, and I can confirm that it is, but the file has no file name, or mimetype associated in Drive, and the response shows the mimeType as `multipart/form-data`.

How should I set the name and mime type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can achieve this using postman. What you need to do is a multipart upload, documented at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multipart-upload, such that you have one part for the metadata (eg. filename) and a second part for the content.

Comment: makes sense, I'm eventually going to be doing it with fetch, but this will do nicely.